# how to distribute neo4j to several machines(is it possible at all)?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, neo4j, distribution

how should I distribute neo4j in order to traverse n numbers of graphs on different machines,concurrently?and each machine returns its result,so the results can be compared with each other(reminds me map reduce,am I right?),and the best be selected?Can that be done?

which tools should I use?hadoop?

I will be really thankful if you give me tutorials too.

Comment: Why do you have to distribute in the first place? How big is your graph, what does your model look like what are your use-cases. Please update your question.

Comment: Doing distributed queries is going to depend on your data model, and it's best not to over-engineer the solution before you need to. what does your use case look like?

Comment: I can't discribe it,I have to show visually after finishing working on it.

Comment: You can take a look at Titan if you really need sharding: http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/

Answer (score 4):

Neo4J distribution is supported through replication of the data, storing the data on a single machine and read it from many machines.

Neo4J doesn't automatically shard the data across multiple machines, this has to be handled at the application layer.

Not sure why this is difficult to implement in a graph database. Noe4J might be offering this feature in their future releases.

Check the [HA](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/ha.html) documentation from Neo4J for more details.

Comment: so this can not be done,or I have to implement it myself with the help of hadoop?

Comment: Sharding has to be done @ application layer (hadoop, x, y z etc) and not supported by Neo4J for now.

Comment: Sharding is difficult for Graph databases in the same way that it is for RDBMS, in that you have entities that are related to one another, so you may have to traverse the network barrier a lot, and cutting down on this can be difficult.